# Get PID and return code from 1 line bash call

Tags: bash, process, subshell, exit-status

Imagine we have a long command `sleep 10` (for instance). We would like to execute it on another server using python (the ssh library `paramiko` to be specific).

I need a 1 line command that starts the command, prints the PID of the command, and then waits for it to finish and finally returns the exit status of the command.

What I've tried so far:

```
bash -c "echo $BASHPID ; exec sleep 10" ; echo $?
```

This prints the PID of the shell, then calls exec on the long command, and then waits and prints the exit status. The problem is `$BASHPID` prints the PID of the outer bash shell (possibly indicating calling `bash -c cmd` doesn't actually spawn a full new shell?).

If I call the above command in three lines, it works.

```
bash
echo $BASHPID ; exec sleep 10
echo $?
```

Any attempt using subshells hasn't worked for me either.

```
echo $(echo $BASHPID ; exec sleep 10) ; echo $?
```

This works, but the subshell pipes all of its output to echo, and echo prints it all at once, meaning the `$BASHPID` doesn't get print until after the sleep finishes. The PID must be print immediately.

Comment: tried single-quoting it? double-quotes allow the outer bash to interpolate variables.

Comment: I think that's it.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run, for example:

> bash -c "echo $BASHPID ; exec sleep 10"

or

> echo $(echo $BASHPID ; exec sleep 10)

your current shell is interpolating the `$BASHPID` variable before the second bash (or subshell) sees it. The solution is to prevent the expansion of those variables by the current shell:

```
bash -c 'echo $BASHPID ; exec sleep 10'
```

Answer (score 4):

That's a shell command you run over `ssh` already (interpreted by the login shell of the remote user), no need to start another shell on top of that. Assuming that shell is Bourne-like or csh-like:

```
echo "$$"; exec sleep 10
```

should be enough. No need to install `bash` on the remote host. `ssh` will also report the exit status of the remote command, no need to print it. But if you have to, you can do:

```
sleep 10 & echo "$!"; wait; echo "$?"
```

Not for csh-like shells as `$?` is `$status` instead there.

If you can't guarantee the login shell of the remote user be Bourne-like, you could do:

```
exec sh -c 'sleep 10 & echo "$!"; wait; echo "$?"'
```

That command should be compatible to shells of the Bourne, csh and rc families at least.

Comment: The second one worked for me (it is simpler than the one I was attempting). The only problem is there is latency when getting the PID because the syscall has to finish. I put in a quarter second timeout and it works great.

Comment: As it turns out, this middle command (what I was using) doesn't work. I believe the return code from echo "$?" returns the code for wait, not from sleep 10. My attempt and the correct answer above actually do return the correct return code of the running subprocess.